# Advice on converting large nested XML documents to CSV using XSLT or SAX/DOM/OTHER??

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, saxparser

Trying to convert XML document to CSV format. Which is the best method to do this? I've seen many people suggest XSLT and others suggest some sort of parser. Just trying to get a better idea on what to use. 
Few things to consider are: 
Let's say XML file is nested a bit (let's say 3 in depth). Also what if I wanted to include a header for csv file which would be the attribute names but not all parent nodes may have the same number of children. For example:

```
<phones>    
 <phone>
  <mobile>555-555-5555</mobile>
  <work>231-234-3333</work>
  <home>206-444-7777</home>
 </phone>
 <phone>
   <home>999-999-9999</home>
 </phone>
</phones>
```

Output would be something as:

```
mobile,work,home
555-555-5555,231-234-3333,206-444-7777
,,999-999-9999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, XSLT would be the best tool to transform an XML into text, csv, other XML, etc.

The question of populating headers, in XSLT, can be a literal string as following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/phones">
    <xsl:text>mobile,work,home&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="phone"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="phone">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(mobile, ',', work, ',', home, '&#xa;')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```